# upgrading Red Hat Satellite Server

Tags: upgrade, redhat, satellite

Trying to upgrade Red Hat Satellite 6 to 6.1

typing in this:
subscription-manager repos --disable rhel-6-server-satellite-6.0-rpms

is giving this:
Error: rhel-6-server-satellite-6.0-rpms is not a valid repository ID. Use --list option to see valid repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are following

[Upgrade guide for Satellite 6 to 6.1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Satellite/6.1/html/Installation_Guide/chap-Upgrading_Red_Hat_Satellite_and_Capsule_Server.html#sect-Red_Hat_Satellite-Installation_Guide-chap-Upgrading_Red_Hat_Satellite_and_Capsule_Server-Upgrading_Red_Hat_Satellite)

Are you using RHEL 6 or RHEL 7 to install Satellite? You could get this error if you use RHEL 7 and you are trying to change a RHEL 6 subscription

In order to see what respos are enabled:

> # subscription-manager repos --list-enabled

To see all available repos do:

> #$ subscription-manager repos --list

You should find your repo id there, if it is not, check the following

> # subscription-manager list --consumed

And there should be one line with Red Hat Satellite Subscription somewhere if you have attached the subscription to your system